# SharePoint Online Document Library member are unable Access the HomePage of the Site

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-365

First Question and its pretty Newbish

We have Sharepoint online site,
I have created a number of Libraries, such as 
Library A, Library B, Library c, Library D etc

I have creted unique permissions to the libraries and create extra groups.
the Purpose is to Enable only a few Users to access Library B but they should now be able to see the Library A, C D

After creating the unique Permission the Users are unable to access the Home Page of the Site, they all get a access denied message.

How can i add permission so that all the Users can access the site but only see/access the library they are authorized to access.

If I grant the User Read Access on the Site then they can access the site and ALSO see the Document library that they are NOT Supposed to see... lol stuck in a loop...

Kindly help.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
After creating the unique Permission the Users are unable to access the Home Page of the Site, they all get a access denied message.
```

This is expected behavior, you interrupt permission inheritance, users in this group only have access to the library here, they can not access the site.

You don't need to give them Read Access on site.

Because you only want them to access this particular library, you just need to give them the specific URL address of this library (not give them the address of this site)